# sql query with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6, phpmyadmin

I have a weird problem please take a look at this query:

```
select * from myfriend where name like "%n%";
```

when execute this query on phpMyAdmin the query returned correct results, but when execute it using php no result returned.

please note this query executed in drupal 6.

what is the problem with char "n" and PHP?

Comment: additional information: when use any char else "n" the query return results.

Comment: You write like 'select * from myfriend where name like "%n%"'..??

Comment: $query = "select * from myfriend where name like '%n%'";

Comment: This is fine as far as it goes. What comes next?

Comment: $query = "select * from myFriend where name like '%n%'";
$result = db_query($query);
while($row = db_fetch_object($result)){   
   prin_r($row); 
}

Comment: can you paste the code where you are executing the query, db_query() function and also make sure that there are actual records present with "n" character

Comment: `db_query($query)` ? Don't you thing it should me `mysql_query($query)` ?

Comment: $query = "select * from myFriend where name like '%n%'"; $result = db_query($query); while($row = db_fetch_object($result)){ prin_r($row); } ------------ drupal 6

Comment: please note query executed in drupal6 and as i read %n is keyword is this true? because i printed the final query that executed and %n converted to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Percent signs are used as placeholders in Drupal 6 queries, so you need to escape them:

```
$query = db_query('select * from myfriend where name like "%%n%%"');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$searchChar = "n";

$query = "SELECT * FROM `myfriend` WHERE `name` LIKE '%" . $searchChar . "%'";
```

Then use the `$query` variable in your statement.

Eg:

`$mysql->query($query);`

`mysql_query($query);`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is perfect. Give some brief on it. You can check if your connection of database from php to mysql is correct. You can echo that query from php file and run into phpmyadmin if that gives correct output then surely database connectivity problem will be there.

There is absolutely no issues with any character in php.

Comment: Yes, so you can escape "%" sign by putting extra "%" sign in front of them.